# Panonlens - image not loading on the desktop version

Tags: desktop, panoramas, 360-virtual-reality

I'm currently using panolens.js for implementing a 3d view on my website. The responsive version seems to load fine but the problem arises in desktop. The image loaded into the script is only visibile when i open the console or try to inspect the element. Any suggestions?

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="tour-sec">
 <div class="container tour-sec">
   <div class="row">
    <h2>Schedule A Tour</h2>
   <div id="container-1"></div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
const panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama('2pano.jpg');
const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer();
viewer.add(panorama);

$(".panolens-container").detach().appendTo('#container-1');
```